# is it any good to write an internet-based automation system?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, automation, web

i am ordered! to design and implement an automation system for one of government's office, it is mainly a secretariat automation system, and i was thinking of implementing this system as a j2ee web application which will be hosted by apache tomcat and users need to use a browser to access the application.
so i googled a bit and i found no similar product that took my strategy. so the question is, is there any down point with my way? any technical issues maybe? 
thank you and accept my apology for my poor English skills.

Comment: you have to ask a more precise question. The one you asked is soo broad and generic that it'll get closed in no time.

Comment: Yeah, tighten it up.  Is your question about browser-based vs. desktop apps?  Service over the Internet?  What?

Comment: i guess you guys are not familiar with secretariat automation systems. i guess i should have explained it. secretariat automation system are usually desktop applications and i am planning to write a  browser-based one using java EE.

Comment: @dave: This is what's going to happen if one does not provide enough details. Maybe you can further elaborate on the non-functional requirements - which *technical* features must such a system support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First point (down): Do not use **J2EE**. J2EE is *quite* outdated (see [Wikpedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J2ee#Nomenclature.2C_standards.2C_and_specifications)). Use **Java EE 6** instead which includes State-of-the-art dependency injection and JSF >= 2.0.

Second point: What does a "secretary automation system" do? I don't know but I assume mostly some kind of information system.

Therefore the "strategy" as described so far is: "Use a Web-Application to build some custom internal information system. Use the JEE6 stack for this." This is a common strategy.

Comment: thnx for response , it is "secretariat automation system" it is used to reduce and  eliminate paperwork in offices, and i guess we can call it internal information system.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, J2EE and Tomcat are fantastic for browser-internet automation. You're all set!

Comment: this is an internal information system which runs inside a local network, do you think is it any good to be a browser-internet based instead of desktop application ?